# Solr 5.0: Unable to start Solr with Zookeeper Ensemble

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have 3 Zookeeper servers running at `server1:2181, server2:2181` and `server3:2181`.

I want to start 4 Solr servers at `server1:8983,server2:8983,server3:8983` and `server4:8983` to point to Zookeeper Ensemble above. So at server1, I run a command:

```
bin>solr -c -z server1:2181,server2:2181,server3:2181 -m 2g
```

and I received an error message:

```
Missing operand.
Invalid command-line option: server2:2181
Usage:.........
```

**but** if I point to one Zookeeper server such as:

```
bin>solr -c -z server1:2181 -m 2g
```

it starts successfully.

All server running in Windows.

What did I do wrong? Or does the Solr start script in Windows have an error?

Comment: Format code inline with backquotes and on its own with 4 spaces indent. Use **bold** instead of ALLCAPS. Announcements of appreciation don't belong in question (no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your zk connection string in quotes.